# Extending a formula (VLOOKUP) to the whole column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

I created a VLOOKUP formula inside a Google Sheet, I have 130000 lines and need to extend the formula to the end of the column.

Comment: This is the formula I'm using: =VLOOKUP(A10;$B$2:$C$4;2;0)

Comment: I tried also to use =Arrayformula(=VLOOKUP(A10;$B$2:$C$4;2;0)) but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

### First Solution: ARRAYFORMULA

This modified formula should work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A:A;$B$2:$C$4;2;0))
```

### Second Solution: Fill Down

Select the entire column you wish this formula to be in, make sure that the first cell has the formula in it, then press `Ctrl + D`. This should copy down the formula.

Also for the time you ask questions, please key all the information in the actual question. You can edit your question if you have extra information that you forgot to mention.